# Selecting odd/even rows in table with child rows

Tags: html, css

I have a table with alternating row colors. Some rows may be followed by a "sub row" which is dynamically added and contains a single TD tag and spanned across all columns. I want to maintain the alternating row colors as if there were no sub rows. In my example, you can see the last 3 rows (3, 4, 5) all have the same color because of the sub rows.

I hoped I could just do this but it doesn't have the desired effect.

```
tr:not(.childrow):nth-child(odd) { }
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 400px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc
}
.childrow td {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="childrow">
        <td colspan="3">this is a child row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4.1</td><td>4.2</td><td>4.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="childrow">
        <td colspan="3">this is a child row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5.1</td><td>5.2</td><td>5.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Not sure who voted to close this as I already stated the referenced solution link is not the same as my question and contains a very different table structure.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with just CSS. You'll either need to add identifiers (classes, etc.) to the rows needing styling, rearrange the HTML so that the "child rows" are actually children of their preceding rows, or add javascript.

Comment: Not really.  I found a theoretical solution, nth-child(2n of .row) but apparently only safari actually has support for 'of' in this selector.  I thought I could just give each row (except child rows) a class and select odd of the class, but it doesn't seem to affect it any differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, though semantically it's a bad idea. Using a DIV for a child row instead, but this required changing a few properties on the table itself.  Another caveat is, the DIV has to be inserted after the table creation. Placing it in the HTML itself doesn't work (as one would expect).  For me, this isn't an issue as the these child rows are built dynamically after the table creation.

```js
function expand(index){

    row = $('tbody').children('tr')[index];
  
  var tr = $('<div class="childrow">asjdfhakljsdhlfk ahsdjkf hajkldsf</div>');
  
  tr.insertAfter(row);


}


expand(2);
```

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse;width:100%;
display:flex;flex-flow:column;
}
tbody{flex:1 1 auto; display:block;overflow:hidden auto;}
tr{display:table;table-layout:fixed;width:100%}
thead tr{flex: 0 0 auto;}

.childrow {width:100%;height:50px;background:#555;padding:8px;color:white;}

tr:nth-of-type(even){background:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
<thead>
  <tr><th>H 1</th><th>H 2</th><th>H 3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="row"><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td><td>1.3</td></tr>
  <tr class="row"><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td><td>2.3</td></tr>
  <tr class="row"><td>3.1</td><td>3.2</td><td>3.3</td></tr>
  <tr class="row"><td>4.1</td><td>4.2</td><td>4.3</td></tr>
  <tr class="row"><td>5.1</td><td>5.2</td><td>5.3</td></tr>
  <tr class="row"><td>6.1</td><td>6.2</td><td>6.3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```